# How do I create a testbench for my Verilog code?

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I am trying to print the graph of this in Modelsim with Verilog

[image: Boolean function]

This is the code I wrote in Modelsim:

```
module circuit (
input A,
input B,
input C,
input D,
output reg F
);
always @* begin
F = ~(~A & B | B & ~C) | (A & ~D | B & D);
end
endmodule
```

I have to manually change A, B, C and D 16 times to simulate every possibility and print the graph. How do I create a testbench file so I can simulate the graph without manually changing values and pressing Run 16 times?

I tried writing this testbench.v file but it didn't work

```
module testbench;
    reg A, B, C, D;
    wire F;
    
    testbench TEST (
            .a(A),
            .b(B),
            .c(C),
            .d(D),
            .f(F)
        );

    initial begin
      
        A = 0; B = 0; C = 0; D = 0; #10;   
        A = 0; B = 0; C = 0; D = 1; #10;        
        A = 0; B = 0; C = 1; D = 0; #10;
        A = 0; B = 0; C = 1; D = 1; #10;

        A = 0; B = 1; C = 0; D = 0; #10;
        A = 0; B = 1; C = 0; D = 1; #10;
        A = 0; B = 1; C = 1; D = 0; #10;
        A = 0; B = 1; C = 1; D = 1; #10;

        A = 1; B = 0; C = 0; D = 0; #10;
        A = 1; B = 0; C = 0; D = 1; #10;
        A = 1; B = 0; C = 1; D = 0; #10;
        A = 1; B = 0; C = 1; D = 1; #10;

        A = 1; B = 1; C = 0; D = 0; #10;
        A = 1; B = 1; C = 0; D = 1; #10;
        A = 1; B = 1; C = 1; D = 0; #10;
        A = 1; B = 1; C = 1; D = 1; #10;
        
        $finish;
    end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 5):

The testbench did not work because it has multiple issues.
First issue in your `testbench` is that, you need to instantiate your `circuit` module but you have mistakenly instantiated the `testbench` itself that will cause the `illegal recursive design instantiation` error.

Secondly, you have instantiated the your module using the lowercase letters but your actual module ports are defined as uppercase ports. This will give you `cannot find port 'a' on this module` error. Know that Verilog is case sensitive, so you need to change the instantiation accordingly.

```
circuit TEST(
      .A(A),
      .B(B),
      .C(C),
      .D(D),
      .F(F)
);
```

[image: Simulation]

> How do I create a testbench file so I can simulate the graph without manually changing values and pressing Run 16 times?

In the testbench you have already provided all 16 combinations with a delay of `#10`, So you do not need to run it 16 times. You have to just run it once.